# Copy rows from multiple worksheets based on number value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a multiple sales worksheets where the salesmen put among other things, their confidence level for a certain sale.  I have just started learning VBA, so I am not clueless but I have to admit this is over my head.

If a row has a confidence level over 60%, I want the entire row copied to a new worksheet.

The data begins on row 8 and the confidence percentage column is column V.

There are a total of 9 worksheets I want the VBA script to be applied to, they are named:

- Jeff
- John
- Tim
- Pete
- Chad
- Bob
- Kevin
- Mike
- Bill

I want all the rows with a confidence level over  60% copied over to a master or "Install" sheet, beginning once again on row 8.  I want to run the script by a button on the "Install" sheet.

Here is a picture of what I am working with:

[image: excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below

- copies rows 8 down from all your nine sheets (if the names exists) to a sheet called "Install"
- any records less than 60% are autofiltered and deleted from the master sheets (more efficient than autofiltering each of the nine sheets before copying)
- blanks rows are added at the top to start "Install" at row 8

*If you do need header rows from row 1 to 7 then these can be copied from one of the salesman sheets - let me know *

```
Sub QuickCombine()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strShts()
Dim strWs As Variant
Dim lngCalc As Long

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
lngCalc = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set ws1 = Sheets("Install")
ws1.UsedRange.Cells.Clear

strShts = Array("Jeff", "John", "Tim", "Pete", "Chad", "Bob", "Kevin", "Mike", "Bill")
For Each strWs In strShts
On Error Resume Next
Set ws2 = Sheets(strWs)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
Set rng1 = ws2.Range(ws2.[v8], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "v").End(xlUp))
rng1.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "v").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, "A")
End If
Set ws2 = Nothing
Next
With ws1
    .[v1] = "dummy"
    .Columns("V").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<60%"
    .Rows.Delete
.Rows("1:7").Insert
End With
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = lngCalc
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 For the autofilter! It's a much faster way than looping :)

Comment: I just had a thought, this would work fabulously, if the total rows of all the worksheets together doesn't exceed the rows limit of Excel. An alternative could also be to copy the filtered rows from each worksheet to the master sheet. Like I mentioned, it is just a thought... :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout good point, while it's unlikely that the 1M rows would be exceeded by compiling 9 sheets it's worth testing for - I will update

Comment: @brettdj You sir, are amazing!  This worked perfectly!  It would be nice to have the header rows, but I don't want them to be copied every time the code is run, as my client might change/rename the headers a little bit.  I guess I should just do it manually right?

Comment: @brettdj Would it be possible to also exclude all the rows with a blank percentage?  A.K.A is it possible to to exclude all rows with a blank cell in column V?

Comment: @brettdj Okay, this is really pushing it I know, but would it be possible to insert another column into the install sheet with the sheet name from which the row was copied?  E.g. if the row was copied from the "John" worksheet, can the code autoinsert the sheet name ("John") into column A for example?  I don't know how impossible/difficult this would be to implement, so if it is too hard just forget it.